# Why will node.exe not run sample file where cmd.exe will?

Tags: node.js

I've downloaded and run the latest nodejs .msi for Windows (7), updated PATH (`;C:\nodejs`), installed nssm and created a service - all's well there hopefully.

Next, I have a sample server.js file from many an online tutorial and have failed to start the nodejs server via C:\nodejs\node.exe. The nodejs terminal opens, and I can input valid javascript, eg: `["a","b"].join()` and receive output: `"a,b"`. My sample file is in the same dir as node.exe - but when I input "node server.js", all I get is "...", I must CTRL+C to exit that state.

When I open a Windows cmd prompt, `cd C:\nodejs\` and input "node server.js", I receive the expected output from server.js and localhost: 8124 displays the sample message. I then also tried to use npm to install express via node.exe prompt, but couldn't

Why won't node.exe terminal start the sample server, where cmd will?

[image: successful "npm install express" in cmd, the same failed in node.exe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm` is a `.exe` just like `node` is. So you cannot run `npm` inside `node` since `node` is not a real shell but kind of a "JavaScript shell". And `npm install something` is certainly not valid JavaScript.

Comment: ok, so it would be expected that I also couldn't launch a nodejs server from within its js shell? ala input: "node server.js"

Comment: cheers, just making sure i'm not missing out on a bunch of logging or debugging as I'll need it :)

Answer (score 0):

NPM is node.js application. It has its own commands.